# If I installed Mongo through apt-get, how do I update it?

Tags: linux, mongodb, apt-get, aptitude

It seems like they gave me 1.4.4 Which is not the latest.

Is this normal? I want 1.6. But I'm afraid that if I do apt-get uninstall, bad things will happen.

Comment: This question should be moved to elsewhere from StackOverflow.

Comment: @ern0 ... why? Where should it go? Seems to be generally inline with http://stackoverflow.com/faq ...

Comment: @Alesander ... eh maybe, I don't see why it hurts. At least you made a suggestion however.

Comment: I'm borderline, because it is about a tool programmers use.  However, it is also too localized (in the sense of time).

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend using the official Ubuntu and Debian packages ...

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Ubuntu+and+Debian+packages

That'll make sure you'll always get the latest *stable* version. If you use this on Ubuntu (for example) MongoDB will install to **/var/lib/mongodb/** (instead of **/data/db/**)

So, if your data is already in **/var/lib/mongodb/** you should be fine doing an uninstall and reinstall from the offical packages ... it shouldn't remove that dir unless it was a horible port in the first place!

*Simply making a backup copy of that dir should do the trick if you are worried, good practice anyhow.*

You can also always move your DB files *into* that dir after the install and MongoDB will pick them up (normally.)

Before you do anything however, just make sure you do a clean shutdown first! That way you won't end up with a **mongod.lock** file which won't let you do a restart w/o a repair.

```
$ ./mongo 
> use admin
> db.shutdownServer()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend not to touch your distribution and operating system version, and go for the simple solution of installing a downloaded package: www.mongodb.org/downloads.
Especially if you are using Debian, since Mongo 1.1.6 is supported only on unstable - packages.debian.org/search?keywords=mongodb

Tip: If you are on Debian or Ubuntu, check this page: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Ubuntu+and+Debian+packages

Answer (score 0):

Installing anything via `apt-get` installs whichever version is the default from all known repositories. By default that only includes your distributions repository (Debian, Ubuntu, ...).

Those repositories contain well-defined, well-tested versions of the software. They don't always get updated to the latest version (or may be somewhat slow).

If you require a specific version (or the latest one), then you need to find a repository that provides that version (possibly provided by the developers of the software) or install it via other means.

Comment: If I apt-get remove mongo, and then install it from source (tar), will that delete my settings/data?

Comment: That depends on where your settings/data are installed. But by default uninstalling packages via `apt-get` will not remove any hand-modified settings.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, this is a question about Debian packaging system. Anyway here it is my suggestion.

Make sure you have listed "unstable" in apt-get sources:

```
# cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/unstable.list 
deb ftp://<your closest debian mirror>/debian/ unstable main contrib non-free
deb-src ftp://<your closest debian mirror>/debian/ unstable main
```

Find your mirror in [the list of mirrors](http://www.debian.org/mirror/list)

Then do

```
apt-get update
apt-get install mongodb-server /unstable
apt-get install mongodb-clients /unstable
```

(be careful if it's your production -- MongoDB will be restarted)

And by the way, the latest version of MongoDB in Debian "unstable" is 1.6.5: [MongoDB in "sid"](http://packages.debian.org/sid/mongodb)

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I get `E: Unable to locate package` on Debian 7...  I miss Arch Linux!